# Bert Tokenizer punctuation for named entity recognition task

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition, punctuation

I'm working on a named entity recognition task, where I need to identify person names, books etc.

I am using Huggingface Transformer package and BERT with PyTorch. Generally it works very good, however, my issue is that for some first names a dot "." is a part of the first name and shouldn't be separate it from it. For example, for the person name "Paul Adam", the first name in the training data is shortened to one letter combined with dot "P. Adam". The tokenizer tokenize it as ["P", ".", "Adam"] which later negatively impact the ner trained model performance as "P." is presented in the training data and not only "P". The model is capable to recognize the full names but fails in the shortened one. I used Spacy tokenizer before and I didn't face this issue. Here more details:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertConfig, AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig, BertModel
path_pretrained_model='/model/bert/'
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(path_pretrained_model)

print(tokenizer.tokenize("P. Adam is a scientist."))

Output:
['p', '.', 'adam', 'is', 'a', 'scientist', '.']

The helpful output would be 
['p.', 'adam', 'is', 'a', 'scientist', '.']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether this might be a viable solution for you, but here's a possible hack.

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertConfig, AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig, BertModel
import string

tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_basic_tokenization=True, never_split=[f"{letter}." for letter in list(string.ascii_lowercase)])

print(tokenizer.tokenize("P. Adam is a scientist."))   
# ['p.', 'adam', 'is', 'a', 'scientist', '.']
```

Indeed, from the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertTokenizer)

> never_split (Iterable, optional) — Collection of tokens which will never be split during tokenization. Only has an effect when do_basic_tokenize=True

Comment: Hi, using your code I got ['p', '##.', 'adam', 'is', 'a', 'scientist', '.']

Comment: @Questioner mm, strange. It seems working on my machine. Which version of `transformers` are you running on? Perhaps, the issue might be related to https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/3518, which has been eventually overcome.

Comment: you are right, updating the transformers to the last version 4.26.1 gave the expecting output